# POCO C++ Libraries. Get full url

Tags: c++, poco-libraries

When I try to `getUri` from response, I get only uri path. Is there any way to get uri fragment from `HTTPResponse`?

```
class TestMyRequestHandler : public HTTPRequestHandler
{
public:
    void handleRequest(HTTPServerRequest &req, HTTPServerResponse &resp)
    {
    resp.setStatus(HTTPResponse::HTTP_OK);
    resp.setContentType("text/html");
    ostream& out = resp.send();

    URI uri(req.getURI());
    clog << uri.toString() << endl;
    }
};

class TestRequestHandlerFactory : public HTTPRequestHandlerFactory
{
public:
    virtual HTTPRequestHandler* createRequestHandler(const HTTPServerRequest &)
    {
        return new TestMyRequestHandler;
    }
};

int main()
{
    HTTPServer test(new TestRequestHandlerFactory, ServerSocket(8080), new HTTPServerParams);
    test.start();
    for(;;)
    {
    }
    test.stop();
}
```

Comment: Does this help: https://github.com/pocoproject/poco/issues/623

Comment: @JerryJeremiah Thanks, this does